# Need sum of distinct values in one MySQL column grouped by the distinct value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL column named "country" in table named "contact".

I need to write a query to return all the distinct countries in that column, and how many times they occur.

I am trying with:

```
SELECT SUM([DISTINCT] country) FROM contact GROUP BY country
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the name of the Country and the number of times that Country appeared in the column:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM Contact
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY count DESC
```

it also returns the countries in order of most to least frequent.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work

```
SELECT COUNT(country) AS Num_of_country, country
FROM Contact 
GROUP BY country
```